# In EmEditor: How to sum up values from two column's cell (in the same row) and store the results in third column?

Tags: emeditor

I have a pipe separated file:
Col1| Col2| Col3
 `12 | 10 |`
 `54 | 17 |`

How I can get in the sum ( 22 & 71 ) in the Col3 ?
Is there a build-in Function for this kind of operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening your CSV (or pipe-separated) file, select the Column 3 by clicking the Column 3 headings, press `Ctrl+H` to bring up the **Replace** dialog box, click the **Advanced** button, click the **Reset** button to make sure all options in the **Advanced** dialog box are default, and click OK.

In the **Replace** dialog box, enter:

**Find:** `.*`

**Replace with:** `\J Number( cell( -1 ) ) + Number( cell( -2 ) )`

Make sure the **In the Selection Only** and **Regular Expressions** options are set.

Click **Replace All**.

[image: EmEditor - Sum values in columns]

**Notes**: If you need to deal with decimal numbers, use: `\J parseFloat( cell( -1 ) ) + parseFloat( cell( -2 ) )` instead for the **Replace with** expression.

**References**: http://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html